# Lookup column name in column

Tags: python, python-polars

Say I have

```py
df = pl.DataFrame({
    'a': [1, 2, 1],
    'b': [2, 1, 2],
    'c': [3, 3, 2],
    'column': ['a', 'c', 'b'],
})
```

```
shape: (3, 4)
┌─────┬─────┬─────┬────────┐
│ a   ┆ b   ┆ c   ┆ column │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---    │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ str    │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╪════════╡
│ 1   ┆ 2   ┆ 3   ┆ a      │
│ 2   ┆ 1   ┆ 3   ┆ c      │
│ 1   ┆ 2   ┆ 2   ┆ b      │
└─────┴─────┴─────┴────────┘
```

I want add a column which, for each row, take the value in the row corresponding to the column in `column`.

Expected output:

```
shape: (3, 5)
┌─────┬─────┬─────┬────────┬────────┐
│ a   ┆ b   ┆ c   ┆ column ┆ lookup │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---    ┆ ---    │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ str    ┆ i64    │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╪════════╪════════╡
│ 1   ┆ 2   ┆ 3   ┆ a      ┆ 1      │
│ 2   ┆ 1   ┆ 3   ┆ c      ┆ 3      │
│ 1   ┆ 2   ┆ 2   ┆ b      ┆ 2      │
└─────┴─────┴─────┴────────┴────────┘
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works even with repeated columns

```
df = pl.DataFrame({
    'a': [1, 2, 1,3],
    'b': [2, 1, 2,4],
    'c': [3, 3, 2,5],
    'column': ['a', 'c', 'b','a'],
})
df.with_row_count('i').join(
    df.with_row_count('i')
        .melt(['i','column'], value_name='lookup')
        .filter(pl.col('column')==pl.col('variable'))
        .select('i','lookup'),
    on='i', how='left').sort('i').drop('i')

shape: (4, 5)
┌─────┬─────┬─────┬────────┬────────┐
│ a   ┆ b   ┆ c   ┆ column ┆ lookup │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---    ┆ ---    │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ str    ┆ i64    │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╪════════╪════════╡
│ 1   ┆ 2   ┆ 3   ┆ a      ┆ 1      │
│ 2   ┆ 1   ┆ 3   ┆ c      ┆ 3      │
│ 1   ┆ 2   ┆ 2   ┆ b      ┆ 2      │
│ 3   ┆ 4   ┆ 5   ┆ a      ┆ 3      │
└─────┴─────┴─────┴────────┴────────┘
```

Here's another way that doesn't use `melt`

```
df.join(
    df.select(pl.col('column').unique().sort()).with_row_count('i'), 
    on='column'
).with_columns(
    lookup=(pl.concat_list('a','b','c').list.get(pl.col('i')))
).drop('i')
```

It works by converting the 'a','b','c' columns into a list column and then using `.get` to extract the index of that list since get will take an expression. For that to work we first have to make a lookup table of what index value abc are. It obviously breaks badly if the existing columns don't perfectly match what's in `column`. Assuming your data is scrubbed in advance then I think this would be faster than the melt.

Answer (score 1):

You can build multiple `when/then` comparisons and use [`pl.coalesce`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.coalesce.html#polars-coalesce) to choose the matches.

```py
columns = df.drop("column").columns # a, b, c

df.with_columns(
   pl.coalesce(
      pl.when(pl.col("column") == col)
        .then(col) 
      for col in columns
   )
   .alias("lookup")
)
```

```py
shape: (3, 5)
┌─────┬─────┬─────┬────────┬────────┐
│ a   ┆ b   ┆ c   ┆ column ┆ lookup │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---    ┆ ---    │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ str    ┆ i64    │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╪════════╪════════╡
│ 1   ┆ 2   ┆ 3   ┆ a      ┆ 1      │
│ 2   ┆ 1   ┆ 3   ┆ c      ┆ 3      │
│ 1   ┆ 2   ┆ 2   ┆ b      ┆ 2      │
└─────┴─────┴─────┴────────┴────────┘
```

Comment: I think this is probably the easiest to read. You could even define columns as df['column']

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work

```py
pl.concat(
    [
        df,
        df.with_row_count("idx")
        .melt(id_vars=["idx", "column"])
        .filter(pl.col("column") == pl.col("variable"))
        .sort("idx")
        .select("value"),
    ],
    how="horizontal",
)
```

```
shape: (3, 5)
┌─────┬─────┬─────┬────────┬────────┐
│ a   ┆ b   ┆ c   ┆ column ┆ lookup │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---    ┆ ---    │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ str    ┆ i64    │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╪════════╪════════╡
│ 1   ┆ 2   ┆ 3   ┆ a      ┆ 1      │
│ 2   ┆ 1   ┆ 3   ┆ c      ┆ 3      │
│ 1   ┆ 2   ┆ 2   ┆ b      ┆ 2      │
└─────┴─────┴─────┴────────┴────────┘
```

Comment: Same thing, but you could write it as a left join: `df.join(df.melt().filter(), on="column", how="left")`

Comment: that work for this example, but I think it wouldn't work if `column` contains repeated elements

Comment: Ah yes, the duplication - didn't think of that - thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame({
    'a': [1, 2, 1],
    'b': [2, 1, 2],
    'c': [3, 3, 2],
    'column': ['a', 'c', 'b'],
})

df = df.with_column(
    pl.col('column').apply(lambda col_name: df[col_name]),
    'lookup'
)

print(df)
```

Comment: thanks but the question's about polars, not pandas

Comment: df = df.with_column(
    pl.col('column').apply(lambda col_name: df[col_name]),
    'lookup'
)

Comment: that works, but apply is generally discouraged. thanks anyway

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).