# PyPolars, get value from column based on value in another column without for loop

Tags: python, dataframe, python-polars

Using PyPolars I'm trying to create a new column containing the value of a column chosen among several based on a condition.

The condition is expressed in a dictionary. The following code should be clear enough to describe more precisely what I'm looking for.

```py
import polars as pl

def do_that_mapping(lf: pl.LazyFrame) -> pl.LazyFrame:
  my_map = {
    "A": "col_1",
    "B": "col_2",
    "C": "col_2",
    "D": "col_3",
    # many more values to map
  }

  for k, v in my_map.items():
    # ofc I don't want to use that in a loop, I'm looking for a way to execute
    # the following line with a native method of Polars and remove the
    # Python iteration on `my_map`
    lf = lf.with_columns(pl.when(pl.col("col_val") == k).then(pl.col(v)).alias("new_col"))

  return lf


x = pl.LazyFrame(
    data={
        "col_val": ["A", "B", "C", "D"],
        "col_1": [22, 1, 54, 82],
        "col_2": [1, 32, 7, 8],
        "col_3": [4, 6, 90, 3],
    },
    schema={
        "col_val": pl.Utf8,
        "col_1": pl.Int16,
        "col_2": pl.Int16,
        "col_3": pl.Int16,
    },
)
x_with_new_col = x.pipe(do_that_mapping)
```

Comment: You can put the iteration into a single `.with_columns()` call and use `pl.coalesce` e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/76688460/

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, you can write an answer with that solution, I will accept it ! Many thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possible approach is to create multiple `pl.when().then()` expressions and use [`pl.coalesce()`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.coalesce.html#polars-coalesce) to produce a single column:

```
df.with_columns(new_col = 
   pl.coalesce(
      pl.when(pl.col("col_val") == k).then(pl.col(v))
      for k, v in my_map.items()
   )
)
```

```
shape: (4, 5)
┌─────────┬───────┬───────┬───────┬─────────┐
│ col_val ┆ col_1 ┆ col_2 ┆ col_3 ┆ new_col │
│ ---     ┆ ---   ┆ ---   ┆ ---   ┆ ---     │
│ str     ┆ i16   ┆ i16   ┆ i16   ┆ i16     │
╞═════════╪═══════╪═══════╪═══════╪═════════╡
│ A       ┆ 22    ┆ 1     ┆ 4     ┆ 22      │
│ B       ┆ 1     ┆ 32    ┆ 6     ┆ 32      │
│ C       ┆ 54    ┆ 7     ┆ 90    ┆ 7       │
│ D       ┆ 82    ┆ 8     ┆ 3     ┆ 3       │
└─────────┴───────┴───────┴───────┴─────────┘
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(
    x
        .join(pl.LazyFrame({'col_val':my_map.keys(), 'col_map':my_map.values()}), on='col_val')
        .with_columns(
            new_col=pl.coalesce(
                pl.when(pl.col('col_map')==x)
                  .then(pl.col(x)) 
                  for x in my_map.values()
                  )
            )
        .drop('col_map').collect()
)
```

First, turn your `my_map` into another frame and join it to x so that the columns you're matching are their own column. Then use a generator inside `coalesce` that checks if the value in the new `col_map` column is equal to the value you're looking for and, if so, return that value. The only not null thing it can return is the thing you want and coalesce will throw away all the null values and keep the first not-null thing it sees.

Alternatively you could melt, filter like this:

```
(
    x
        .with_columns(i=pl.int_range(0,pl.count()))
        .join(
            x
                .join(pl.LazyFrame({'col_val':my_map.keys(), 'col_map':my_map.values()}), on='col_val')
                .with_columns(i=pl.int_range(0,pl.count()))
                .melt(['i', 'col_val','col_map'], value_name='new_col')
                .filter(pl.col('col_map')==pl.col('variable'))
                .select('i','new_col'), 
            on='i')
        .drop('i')
        .collect()
)
```

Comment: This is way more complicated than the accepted answer. Too much abstruse to be maintained.

Comment: @mlisthenewcool I'm terribly sorry you were inconvenienced to have to read it.

Comment: My comment wasn't intended to be rude, I apologize if that's the result.